# concatenation to previous line in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to add an `alias` to my `.bashrc` so that running the following command `> push 123` will add the line `2017-08-29/push/123` (with current date) to the end of a file.

adding the alias:
`alias push='date +%F/push/ >> log.txt ; echo $1 >> log.txt'`
almos does the trick, this adds two rows as follows

```
2017-08-29/push/
123
```

Please help me make it a single row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
push () { date "+%F/push/$1" >> /tmp/pushlog.txt; }
```

This defines a shell function that appends the string to the `/tmp/pushlog.txt` file.

The format string used with `date` incorporates the first command line argument of the shell function.

```
bash-4.4$ push 123
bash-4.4$ push "hello world"
bash-4.4$ push "%s"
bash-4.4$
bash-4.4$ cat /tmp/pushlog.txt
2017-08-29/push/123
2017-08-29/push/hello world
2017-08-29/push/1504041277
```

If you're planning to use `push` to push strings that may be interpreted by `date` (like the last example), and if that's not what you want, then use this instead:

```
push () { printf '%s/push/%s\n' "$(date '+%F')" "$1" >> /tmp/pushlog.txt; }
```

---

The reason you get an unwanted newline in your file is that `date` outputs a newline at the end of its output. This newline is removed when using `date` in `$(...)` as I did in the second implementation of my shell function above.